# Should the navigation bar be on top of the android snackbar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-framelayout, android-snackbar, snackbar

I have a customized class:

```
public final class MySnackbar<AccountT>
    extends BaseTransientBottomBar<MySnackbar<myT>> {
```

with

```
super(findTopMostFrameLayout(parent), content, new MySnackbarAnimation(content));
```

and

when calling `"show()"`, it shows an android snackbar with customized layout.
How can I make it on top of the Android action bar (home, prev buttons)?

[image]

Comment: Did you use a style for display view below the navigation ?

Comment: Nope. What style attribute can cause this anyhow? so I can text search for?

Comment: Check if you have this   <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item> in your style

Comment: How can I make the snackbar above the navigation bar?